# React Redux - Incrementing state variable does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using a "LOAD MORE" button to show 2 results at a time. In the screenshot below the user clicked LOAD MORE once so it displays all 3 results.

When the user navigates away from the page, and comes back, I want to store the last value of pageNo and use it to display number of results.

This is probably a one line change of code but I cant figure out.

I am using Redux and able to store states such as searchedOnce (boolean). But for this particular state - pageNo, I am not able to apply save the incremented value in Redux.
When the user leaves the page and comes back, the state of pageNo changes back to the initial value which is 1. I am expecting this to be 2 because that was the last value store in redux state. I think my dispatch line in  loadMoreClick() needs to change.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { get } from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { FadeIn } from 'animate-components'
import { getSearchResults, setSearchedOnce, setPageNum } from '../../actions/searchresults'
import SearchResult from './Result/searchResult'
import SearchNoResult from './Result/searchNoResult'

class SearchAdvanced extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { formValues: {}, searchedOnce: false, users: [], pageNo: 1 }
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let formValues = { ...this.state.formValues }
    let name = event.target.name
    let value = event.target.value
    formValues[name] = value
    this.setState({ formValues })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.dispatch(setSearchedOnce(true))
    const apiSearchURL = `/api/search/religion/${this.state.formValues.religion}/gender/${this.state.formValues.gender}`
    get(apiSearchURL, { maxContentLength: 400 })
    .then((searchResults) => {
      this.props.dispatch(getSearchResults(searchResults))
    })
  }

  loadMoreClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(setPageNum(this.state.pageNo))
    this.state.pageNo +=1
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.props
    let mapPageNo = this.props.pageNo
    let map_usersList = users.data && users.data.slice(0, this.state.pageNo * 2).map((userlist => (
      <SearchResult key={userlist.id} {...userlist} />
    )))
    let mapSearchedOnce = this.props.searchedOnce
    return (
      <div>
      <FadeIn duration="300ms">
        <div className="mid_rig_inner">
          <div className="mid_inner">
            <ul>
            { mapSearchedOnce
              ?  map_usersList
              :  <SearchNoResult/>
            }
            {
              mapSearchedOnce ?
              (this.state.pageNo * 2 >= 3)
              ?
              <div className="text-center my3 text-danger">
                No more profiles. Try to modify search criteria.
              </div> :
              <div className="text-center my3">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.loadMoreClick.bind(this)}>
                   Load More
                </button>
              </div>
              : ''
            }
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="rig_inner">
          <div className="my-4">
            <div className="recomm">

                  name="religion"
                  className="mb-2"
                  value={this.state.formValues['religion']}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                >
                  <option value="" disabled="">
                    Select Religion
                  </option>
                  <option value="Any">Any Religion</option>

                  <option>No Religion</option>
                  <option>Other</option>
                </select>

                <select
                  name="gender"
                  className="mb-2"
                  value={this.state.formValues['gender']}
                  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                >
                  <option value="" disabled="">
                    Select Gender
                  </option>


  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.Result.users,
  searchedOnce: state.Result.searchedOnce,
  pageNo: state.Result.pageNo
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchAdvanced)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use local state for `pageNo`.  It looks like your component has `pageNo` as a prop and as local state.  This is confusing for devs, and likely where you're getting tripped up.  If `this.props.dispatch(setPageNum(this.state.pageNo))` is correctly storing the `pageNo` in a reducer, then just rely on `this.props.pageNo`.  Delete `pageNo` from your local state entirely.

Local state is destroyed when your component unmount.  And consequently, when the user navigates away and back, the `this.state.pageNo` is reset. The `pageNo` value stored in redux will not reset when the component unmounts.

Try replacing `this.state.pageNo` with `this.props.pageNo`.  Remember, you can't modify `this.props.pageNo` directly.  You can only do so through your setPageNum action creator.  i.e. `this.props.dispatch(setPageNum(this.props.pageNo + 1))` or whatever you'd like to set it to.

Comment: Yes, works great after I got rid of local state. I was missing the initial state for the reducer too. Now its all good. Thanks for your help.